# Protocol associatedType and <>

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

what is a difference between using generic with function or using associatedType in swift protocols?

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype T
    func add(data : T) -> Bool
}
```

and

```
protocol Repository {
    func add<T>(data : T) -> Bool
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Defined associated type makes classes which conform protocol strong typed. This provide compile-time error handling.

In other hand, generic type makes classes which conform protocol more flexible.

For example:

```
protocol AssociatedRepository {
    associatedtype T
    func add(data : T) -> Bool
}

protocol GenericRepository {
    func add<T>(data : T) -> Bool
}


class A: GenericRepository {
    func add<T>(data : T) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class B: AssociatedRepository {
    typealias T = UIViewController
    func add(data : T) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

class `A` could put any class into `add(data:)` function, so you need to makes your sure that function handle all cases.

```
A().add(data: UIView())
A().add(data: UIViewController())
```

both would be valid

But for class `B` you will get compile-time error when you will try to put anything except `UIViewController`

```
B().add(data: UIView()) // compile-time error here
B().add(data: UIViewController())
```

Answer (score 4):

- An `associatedtype` is a static type in struct/class which adopts the protocol either via a `typealias` declaration or via type inference. The type is always the same for that class.
- A generic can be anything, even different types in the same class.

Answer (score 3):

This case

```
protocol Repository {
    func add<T>(data : T) -> Bool
}
```

Is understood by compiler like: "Any type that is fed to the `func add` will be acceptable and the result of the function will be `Bool`"

But this

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype T
    func add(data : T) -> Bool
}
```

is understood by compiler like: "`func add` will accept only the type that is defined in the `typealias T = ...` and return `Bool`"

In the second case you restrict generic parameters only to the typealiased types.

Another important feature shows up when you use generic parameters in multiple functions of the protocol. In that case it guarantees that `func add<T>` and `func multiply<T>` will have the same type `T`. In case of generic functions it is not guaranteed.

```
protocol Calculable {
    associatedtype T
    func add<T>(a: T, b: T) -> T
    func multiply<T>(a: T, b: T) -> T
}
// In this case you know that T is the same for all functions

protocol CalculableDifferent {
    func add<T>(a: T, b: T) -> T
    func multiply<T>(a: T, b: T) -> T
}
// In this case add can accept One type, when multiply can accept Another
```